# Plotting values onto a histogram in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, statistics, histogram, ranking

I realize there are several [histogram gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=histogram), but my question is a bit unique. I don't need a graph or image of any kind. My rails app has an algorithm that gives each user a score between 0 and 1. e.g. billybob's `raw_score` might be .00901 and frankiejoe's `raw_score` might be .00071.

Without going into why I want to do this, I'd like to plot these values on a histogram, then map the mean `raw_score` as 50% and the mean plus standard deviation at about 65% (the mean minus standard deviation at 35%), the mean plus 2 x standard deviation at 80% etc. So 15 percentile for each standard deviation unit.

I don't need the actual histogram chart/image, I just want their corresponding histogram values after being loaded onto a histogram. I am essentially converting the numbers into a more aesthetically pleasing score, e.g. billybob's `histogram_score` might now be .987 and frankiejoe's might be .471. For now, it's only dozens of users or scores, but I'd like ability to handle thousands of users/scores.

I'd like to store the converted value into my database. The numbers I have now are `raw_score:decimal` and I'll store them as `histogram_score:decimal`.

How might I do this in my rails app?

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a rails question, i think: the important part here is an algorithm for producing the stats that you want.  Ultimately all of your number wrangling will need to happen before you draw the histogram, and drawing the histogram is the easy part, as you've said there are lots of solutions.  (I like Google Charts).  I don't think " I just want their corresponding histogram values after being loaded onto a histogram" really makes sense - it's an array of numbers which you need to transform into another array in order to make the chart you want.  The chart isn't part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. So the [descriptive_statistics](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/descriptive_statistics) gem is going to accomplish this for me.

```rb
require 'descriptive_statistics'
data = [0.15, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.35, 0.10]
data.map {|score| data.percentile_rank(score)}
 => [66.66666666666666, 83.33333333333334, 50.0, 16.666666666666664, 100.0, 50.0]
```

In my case, I'm just looping through each user's raw_score and storing it as the percentile_score. Works great!